# Where should I put "run once" plugin pages?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, user-interface

Where should I put an administration page that should only be used once?

I am creating a plugin that will index all used HTML tags in your posts, so you can cleanup posts if you change themes and want to replace old incorrect `<font>` tags with headers or other semantic markup. When you install this plugin it should scan your old posts once to fill up the index (custom taxonomy). I don't want to do this on plugin installation because it might take a long time if you have many posts, and thus a separate page with an AJAX-approach to transform batches of posts might be better.

It's probably nitpicking, but should I put this extra page in the menu (under *Tools*?) and just leave it there, or should a use a trick to only display it when needed? Via a link in the plugin actions, or maybe a DB setting that you can use to hide the menu item? The plugin should remain installed (because it updates on post inserts and edits), and maybe sometimes you want a rescan (if you did a bulk change via the database).

As plugin users, does it bother you to have menu options that you almost never use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it under Tools seems reasonable to me. Hiding it after a certain action might cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Scribu.
I use Regenerate Thumbnails ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ ), and it is found under tools.  It kind of a run once and forget about it plugin.

Comment: Yes, but Regenerate Thumbnails is really a run-once plugin, you can remove it once you ran it. So that would be different. But thanks for your input, and welcome to the site. I hope to see more good questions and answers from you in the future!